# listview(custom adapter) with media player android

Tags: java, android, listview

Hey guys i am facing problem in listview(custom adapter).I have implemented listview with media player that plays audio(mp3 file).I have included mp3 files in my raw folder. I know this is a recycle view.My problem is after 6-7 rows same mp3 file is played same as the file that was on 0th position. 
any solution to this?
My main activity
    public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener {

```
    ListView lview3;
    ListViewCustomAdapter adapter;
    private ArrayList<Object> itemList;
    private ItemBean bean;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);


        prepareArrayLits();
        lview3 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        adapter = new ListViewCustomAdapter(this, itemList);
        lview3.setAdapter(adapter);

        lview3.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position1, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ItemBean bean = (ItemBean) adapter.getItem(position1);

        Toast.makeText(this, "Title => "+bean.getTitle()+" \n Description => "+bean.getDescription(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    /* Method used to prepare the ArrayList,
     * Same way, you can also do looping and adding object into the ArrayList.
     */
    public void prepareArrayLits()
    {
        itemList = new ArrayList<Object>();

        AddObjectToList(R.drawable.ic_add, "Add", "Add desc",R.raw.mp1);
        AddObjectToList(R.drawable.ic_delete, "Delete", "Delete desc",R.raw.mp2);
        AddObjectToList(R.drawable.ic_down, "Down", "Down desc",R.raw.mp3);
        AddObjectToList(R.drawable.ic_info, "Information", "Information desc",R.raw.mp4);
        AddObjectToList(R.drawable.ic_help, "Help", "Help desc",R.raw.mp5);
        AddObjectToList(R.drawable.ic_download, "Download", "Download desc",R.raw.mp6);
        AddObjectToList(R.drawable.ic_mail, "Mail", "Mail desc",R.raw.mp7);
        AddObjectToList(R.drawable.ic_search, "Search", "Search desc",R.raw.mp8);
        AddObjectToList(R.drawable.ic_settings, "Settings", "Settings desc",R.raw.mp9);
    }

    // Add one item into the Array List
    public void AddObjectToList(int image, String title, String desc,int audio)
    {
        bean = new ItemBean();
        bean.setDescription(desc);
        bean.setImage(image);
        bean.setTitle(title);
        bean.setAudio(audio);
        itemList.add(bean);
    }
}
```

my listviewCustomadapter

```
public class ListViewCustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
    MediaPlayer mPlayer;
    Context c;
    ArrayList<Object> itemList;

    public Activity context;
    public LayoutInflater inflater;

    public ListViewCustomAdapter(Activity context, ArrayList<Object> itemList) {
        super(context, R.layout.main);

        this.context = context;
        this.itemList = itemList;
        this.c = context;
        this.inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return itemList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return itemList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    public static class ViewHolder {
        ImageView imgViewLogo;
        TextView txtViewTitle;
        TextView txtViewDescription;
        Button btn1, btn2;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.items, null);

            holder.imgViewLogo = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgViewLogo);
            holder.btn1 = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button);
            holder.btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (position == 0) {
                        mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getContext(), R.raw.mp1);
                        mPlayer.start();
                    }
                    if (position == 1) {
                        mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getContext(), R.raw.mp2);
                        mPlayer.start();
                    }
                    if (position == 2) {
                        mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getContext(), R.raw.mp3);
                        mPlayer.start();
                    }
                    if (position == 3) {
                        mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getContext(), R.raw.mp4);
                        mPlayer.start();
                    }
                    if (position == 4) {
                        mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getContext(), R.raw.mp5);
                        mPlayer.start();
                    }
                    if (position == 5) {
                        mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getContext(), R.raw.mp6);
                        mPlayer.start();
                    }
                    if (position == 6) {
                        mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getContext(), R.raw.mp7);
                        mPlayer.start();
                    }
                    if (position == 7) {
                        mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getContext(), R.raw.mp8);
                        mPlayer.start();
                    }
                    if (position == 8) {
                        mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getContext(), R.raw.mp9);
                        mPlayer.start();
                    }


                }
            });


            holder.btn2 = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button2);
            holder.txtViewTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtViewTitle);
            holder.txtViewDescription = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtViewDescription);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

        ItemBean bean = (ItemBean) itemList.get(position);

        holder.imgViewLogo.setImageResource(bean.getImage());
        holder.txtViewTitle.setText(bean.getTitle());
        holder.txtViewDescription.setText(bean.getDescription());

        return convertView;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just because convertView becomes reused.
Set `holder.btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { ...` even if `(convertView != null)`.

Also it could be better to use single MediaPlayer for all view items than creating it again and again.

Comment: Thanks mahn u rock :) .